# Is this shower plumbed correctly?

Tags: plumbing, shower, valve, plumbing-fixture

I had a plumber install a Thermostatic Shower System w/ handheld this week (https://www.signaturehardware.com/lexia-thermostatic-shower-system-with-slide-bar-and-hand-shower/953779.html)

Both the shower and handheld are 1.8 GPM each. There are 3 valves - one for mixing, one for volume and another diverter. However after inspecting their work today, it looks to have a few issues.

If I am reading the instructions correctly, they installed the diverter before the volume (and put the volume over by the handheld?) The instructions are poorly laid out, but here they are: https://signaturehdwr.a.bigcontent.io/v1/static/953779-lexia-thermostatic-showersystem-handshower-installation-trilingual

In the mixing valve, they step up from 1/2" Pex to 3/4" Pex - can you step up like that? I am ignorant of professional plumbing but that doesn't make sense to me in theory. The runs to the shower/handheld are about 12 feet.

Is there anything else you notice wrong?

I have had issues with this plumber previously (like installing check valves the wrong direction) so I am skeptical of their work. If I am off base, sorry for the pessimism!

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's certainly a lesson in why we have the adage 'measure twice, cut once'.

Comment: IMO page 10 of the instructions is pretty clear that if there is a "volume control" in the system then it goes between the mixer and diverter/transfer valve. I couldn't say how you're supposed to marry that with the rough-in dimensions on pages 4 & 6 though...

Comment: @brhans that was my thought as well. The instructions are pretty bad but when there are 3 the volume should be in the middle. I think how they have it now you couldn’t shut off the water to the shower head ever.

Comment: @Tetsujin is there any damage to the rough in valves if they have to redo this?

Comment: @NJC - honestly, that's beyond my skillset. I'm not a plumber, but my father & brother were, so I know what an install *should* look like & what it shouldn't. That one is sloppy.

Comment: The valves all have threaded connectors in this case and it looks like crimpex pipe so you can redo easily without damage.

Comment: why do you have 4 top plates?

Comment: @FreshCodemonger I’m not sure tbh. Half the addition is vaulted, not sure if that has anything to do with it.